# How to handle clicks in chrome extension popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was creating a chrome extension which has a login popup. I am supposed to send the login form data to a backend API in order to get an auth token. I want to then save this token in local storage and change the login popup to another popup which would have 'signout' button. This button would delete the auth token from local storage and again change back the popup to login. I have written the following code to perform the same:

**popup.html**

```
<html>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <div id="welcome" align="left">
    <h3>TimeTracker</h3>
    <form id="login_form" method="post" name="login_form">
      <label>Email :</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
      <br /><br />
      <label>Password :</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
      <br /><br />
      <button type="submit" id="login">Login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var signin_btn = document.getElementById("login");

  signin_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    validate();
  });
});

function validate() {
  var username = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      auth_token = JSON.parse(this.responseText)["token"];
      localStorage.setItem("auth_token", auth_token);
      console.log("auth from popup.js: ", auth_token);
      chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "popup_signed_in.html" });
    }
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/userauth/login", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password }));
  };
}
```

**popup_signed_in.html**

```
<html>
  <script src="popup_signed_in.js"></script>
  <div align="center">
    Dont waste time! Timetracker is monitoring your productivity
    <br />
    <br />
    <button id="signout">Sign out</button>
  </div>
</html>
```

**popup_signed_in.js**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var signout_btn = document.getElementById("signout");

  signout_btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    signout();
  });
});

function signout() {
  localStorage.removeItem("auth_token");
  chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "popup.html" });
}
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TimeTracker",
    "description": "Track your web and app browsing habbits!",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "Tarun Khare",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "Just observing your current url.",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "http://127.0.0.1:5000/*", "storage"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    }
}
```

But when I fill login details and click on 'Login', nothing happens. Neither the popup changes, nor any error or log is displayed in console. I am assuming that there is some problem with my form and event listener, and thus the `validate()` function is not executing. What is the issue?

Comment: After changing the browserAction `chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "popup_signed_in.html" });` You will also need to redirect to `popup_signed_in.html`. Use `window.location.href = "popup_signed_in.html";`

Answer (score 0):

- `chrome.browserAction.setPopup` won't switch the popup immediately.
  For that you need `location.href = "popup_signed_in.html"`
- `xhttp.open` and subsequent lines should be moved out of `xhttp.onreadystatechange`

  ```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      //.......
    }
  };
  xhttp.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/userauth/login', true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ email: username, password: password }));
  ```
- `"http://127.0.0.1:5000/*"` can be `"http://127.0.0.1/"` - no need to specify the port or `*`
- The popup is a separate window so it has its own devtools where you can debug the code and see the errors: right-click inside the popup, then click "inspect".

Comment: I did the things you mentioned. In the inspect console of popup, I still cant see anything. Also no request or error is logged in the server. which probably means extension is not able to send request to the API.

Comment: I tried to console.log("username is: ", username) from inside validate() function and all I can see is the text "username is: " flashing just for a second in console and then disappearing. This probably means I am not able to retrieve username through document.getElementById("email").value

Comment: Devtools can help you much more - you can set breakpoints in your source code and debug it line by line to see what's actually happening and the values of the variables during each step. You can also see the network requests in its network panel. Look for a tutorial on using devtools to debug the code and network requests.

Comment: Also make sure to reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page after editing manifest.json